# Best way for constructing a unique list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, performance, generic-list

I'm wondering whether it will be quicker to follow one pattern or another for constructing a unique list of objects in C#:

Option 1

- Add all the items into a generic list
- Call the list.Distinct function on it

Option 2

- Iterate over each item
- Check whether the item already exists in the list and if not add it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

> The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.

You can provide custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100.aspx) via constructor.

Comment: Thanks, though it's a quote from MSDN.

Comment: A `HashSet<T>` isn't actually a list -- it doesn't preserve order and doesn't provide indexed access. (Not that the OP seems to be aware of the distinction, either.)

Comment: @DavidMoles indeed `HashSet<T>` isn't a `List<T>`. It seems that OP simply wasn't aware of `HashSet`, so this is why I've proposed it as a solution. Because of this, I think, that we can assume that word "list" (in this case) means something being a collection of items.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those "should I use a shoe or a brick to pound a nail into the wood" questions. You should use the appropriate data structure for the job, which based on your requirement of "constructing a unique list of objects", the [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) class satisfies.

If you require the items in list format, you can always call `ToList()` on the set.

Comment: Actually it is a [Shoe or glass bottle](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx).

Comment: A `HashSet<T>` isn't actually a list -- it doesn't preserve order and doesn't provide indexed access. (Not that the OP seems to be aware of the distinction, either.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the performance of looking up unique items, use a [`Dictionary<TKey, TVale>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). Also, a dictionary requires unique keys, so you will never have duplicates.

Comment: Based on the description he doesn't have a key-value relationship, so instead of a Map (one implementation in C# is a `Dictionary`) he needs a Set (such as a `HashSet`).

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about Hashset.